# Worpress - Setting any page to be the static home page results in multiple hyperlinks wrapping the content

Tags: wordpress

I don't work with Wordpress much so I may not be understanding something.

I have used WP and a business template to make a static website. Its meant to be a business site rather than a blog.  I have made a custom home page and in Settings > Reading I have set the homepage to be a static page, choosing that custom page I made.

Let's say I have a page called "about-us".  It lives at mysite.com/about-us.  When I visit that page, everything looks fine, content is what it should be.  But, if I set that page, as I mentioned above, to be the static homepage, suddenly the whole thing becomes a link, and the code is littered with empty A tags linking to the main site url, mysite.com. To clarify, on any page I set to be the static homepage, all the content becomes a giant link that essentially refreshes the site when clicked, not to mention behaves as links with rollover states. Please see the image below for an example of what happens to the code.

This is driving me crazy. I've searched the ends of the internet trying to understand why that happens and more importantly how to stop it.  I would expect any "custom" page I make and set to the homepage to look and behave as I had written it.

Someone please help me understand what I am missing!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can have only one homepage. Essentially only one index.html in the root directory. You can see more information here regarding static front pages: https://wordpress.org/support/article/creating-a-static-front-page/